# Trying to write the contents of a .txt file into a string and instead getting (null)

Tags: objective-c, string, nsurl

I'm trying write the contents of a .txt file into a string and instead getting (null). Any thoughts?

```
    NSURL *desktopURL = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] URLForDirectory:NSDesktopDirectory inDomain:NSUserDomainMask appropriateForURL:nil create:NO error:nil];

    NSURL *shortcutURL = [desktopURL URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"note.txt"];

    NSString *content = [[NSString alloc]initWithContentsOfURL:shortcutURL encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];

    NSLog(@"%@", content);
```

Thanks!

Comment: 1) Does `shortcutURL` appear to be the right path? 2) Is the file stored in UTF-8 encoding?

Comment: Whoops, the encoding was the problem. I changed it to NSUTF16StringEncoding and it worked. Thanks rmaddy!